# How can i get my .net core razor project to reference a newer dll file?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, razor-pages

I am new to .net core and currently am following along a razor page tutorial and trying a few things.  First we created a DataLibrary that consists of the database and stored procedures as well as the models and data access classes.  we published that to the local DB and it generated a dll.  Then we created another project/solution and copied that dll in so we can access it.

It was working fine until I realized I didn't need certain fields so i deleted the field and made sure there are no more references to it and was able to re publish it successfully.  I copied the new dll file back into the 2nd project/solution again, but when i ran it, it is saying that I need to enter a valid date for that field I deleted it.  So it is acting as if I am still referencing the old dll.  I tried rebooting the PC and also made sure I removed that original dll before I copied the new dll over.  I made sure I am referencing the new dll from Dependencies in solution explorer.  I am using visual studio 2019  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to invest in creating a nuget package or using project references. Directly referencing dlls is an older way of doing things.

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks for the comment. Unfortunately i'm new and i'm taking whatever tutorials i'm going through at the moment. I will definitely note that.